# RecyclerView horizontal lo muestra en vertical

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, recyclerview

trato de hacer un Recyclerview con orientación horizontal en el que no soy capaz de meter los elementos de dicha manera.

De primeras defino dicho RecyclerView para que ocupe todo el ancho y largo de elemento padre y pongo horientación horizontal:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/digimonFields"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Al RecyclerView le paso un adapter para que vaya metiendo los elementos que quiero, en este caso imágenes que ocupan 32px:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".view.AttributeAdapter">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/unknown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pero siempre me sale un resultado como este de aquí, y no se qué tengo que hacer para que se vean las imágenes en horizontal...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el XML donde defines el RecyclerView añadele el atributo `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un `RecyclerView` mostrará sus elementos de forma predeterminada en orientación vertical,

```
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

si deseas que se muestren los elementos en orientación Horizontal, define esta propiedad en el `LayoutManager` (`LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL`):

```
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

---

Revisa este ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-RecyclerView-HorizontalVertical

[image: REcyclerView Jorgesys]

Comment: Perfecto, es que como ponía esto: 
addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context,DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL)) creía que ya se tenía que poner así. Gracias. Ahora tengo otro problema que solucionar, pero todo bien!